# Access element of my states in my effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-selectors

I'm new to the ngrx world.

I'm trying to get data of my state directly in my effects.

The idea is get a type of account (publisher or advertiser) and send this information to a "success" action.

this is my effects:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { map, exhaustMap, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import * as fromRoot from '@app/store';
import * as fromActions from './auth.actions';
import * as fromRouter from '@app/store/router';
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";

@Injectable()
export class AuthEffects {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private actions$: Actions,
        private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
    ){}


    signIn$ = createEffect(() => 
        this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(fromActions.Types.LOG_IN),
            map((action: fromActions.LogIn) => action.payload),
            withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromRouter.getAccountRole)),
            exhaustMap(([payload]) => {
                return this.authService.logIn(payload.email, payload.password).pipe(
                    map((user) => {
                        return new fromActions.LogInSuccess({token: user.token, type:'advertiser'})
                    })
                )
            })
        )

    )
}
```

And this is my selector

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from "@ngrx/store";
import { RouterReducerState } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { RouterStateUrl } from "./router.serializer";

export const getRouterState = createFeatureSelector<RouterReducerState<RouterStateUrl>>('router');

export const getCurrentRoute = createSelector(
    getRouterState,
    (router) => router.state
)

export const getAccountRole = createSelector (
    getCurrentRoute,
    (route: RouterStateUrl) => {
        if(route.params['role']) {
            return route.params['role'];
        }
    }
)
```

I think I need to use withLatestFrom before exhaustMap but couldn't use it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, you need to use the `withLatestFrom` operator to before `exhaustMap`, however, I think you missed passing the selector to the `store.select()` method.

Try something like the following:

```js
signIn$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(fromActions.Types.LOG_IN),
        map((action: fromActions.LogIn) => action.payload),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getAccountRole)),
        exhaustMap(([payload, accountRole]) => {
            return this.authService.logIn(payload.email, payload.password).pipe(
                map((user) => {
                    return new fromActions.LogInSuccess({ token: user.token, type: 'advertiser' });
                })
            );
        })
    )
);
```

Comment: thank @Amer you for your help and encouragement.
I have passed the selector
like this:
`withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromRouter.getAccountRole))`.
But if i do that i have an error on my console. 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')

Comment: Could you please provide more details on where exactly do you get this console error? in which file, line exactly?

Comment: I will update my question with the full file code.
If i add the `withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getAccountRole))` operator. when the page reload i have an error in this compiled file core.mjs:6485.
The error point a probleme in this part of my selector file
`export const getCurrentRoute = createSelector(
    getRouterState,
    (router) => router.state
)`

Comment: I think the new problem is related to your RouterState setup. Make sure that you imported the `StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot()` in your AppModule, try to use the default RouterState's selectors, see more: https://ngrx.io/guide/router-store/selectors#creating-a-selector-for-a-single-entity-with-id-as-route-param